# JQuery UI Autocomplete automatically fire (IE)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, user-interface, autocomplete

I have a very bad problem with JQuery Autocomplete and the Internet Explorer.

First I have a input field with a special char value like:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" value="Häskell">
</div>
```

Then my JQuery UI Autocomplete Code looks like

```
$(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Häskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
```

Now when i visit the site with the Internet Explorer, the autocomplete automatically fire and show me the entry "Häskell". (You also can press F5 to reproduce the bug)
But that only happens when the input field value has a special char like ä, ö, ...

I also found a Bug Ticket http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9796#no1

Can somebody help me please?

Big thanks!

Comment: There are some solutions over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584016/jquery-ui-autocomplete-unwanted-triggering-due-to-special-characters that might help  you out.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent such event you should a bit modify jquery ui (it is real bug of IE and partially jquery). Problem is in next feature. IE rises event "input" where another browers does not rise it. 
before modifying this function has next view:

```
input:function(e) {
  if (r) {
    r =! 1, e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  this._searchTimeout(e)
}
```

---

You should modify it to next

```
input:function(e) {
  if (r || typeof(r) == "undefined") {
    r =! 1, e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  this._searchTimeout(e)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

also faces this problem, but with any input value on initialization. Resolved by adding timeout.

```
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("selector").autocomplete({
           // autocomplete options
        }),
    1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced this issue with input value contained Cyrillic letters.

I've implemented the following workaround without hacking jQuery UI autocomplete widget code. Comparing to previous solutions, it can be implemented in local context. So it might be useful when you initialize autocomplete on form elements within, e.g. your own stationary jQuery plug-in.

```
var flagAutoCompleteInitDone;

// we assume that user will not start fill-in the form immediately
setTimeout(function(){flagAutoCompleteInitDone =true;}, 1000);

$('selector')
    .each(function(){  // IE11 hack
        // first we handle 'input' event and prevent its further propagation
        // until our variable is initialized with setTimeout() handler call
        this.addEventListener('input', 
            function(ev){   
                if( typeof flagAutoCompleteInitDone === 'undefined'){
                    ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
                }
            }, false);
    }) // /IE11 hack
    .autocomplete({
        /* your autocomplete options */
    });
```

Tested on jQueryUI ver. 1.11.4 and jQuery 1.6.1+